# Cannot install JAVA silently

Tags: windows-7, java, 32-bit, silent-install

I am trying to install Java in silent mode from a batch file with the command

```
jre-8u60-windows-i586 INSTALLCFG=jresilent.properties
```

The properties file is in the same folder like the JRE installer.

Whatever I do, I get the error

```
---------------------------
Java Installation Not Completed
---------------------------
Unable to install Java

There are errors in the following switches:
"INSTALLCFG=jresilent.properties";.

Check that the commands are valid and try again.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

[image: Java Silent Error Message]

I have tried:

1. renaming the file to end with `.properties` (was `.cfg` before)
2. use different line endings (Linux / Windows)
3. minimize the number of options in the config file to just `REBOOT=Disable`
4. run as administrator
5. explicitly `cd /d` into the directory of the installer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked when I specified the full path of the config file. Therefore I now use

```
cd /d %~dp0
jre-8u60-windows-i586 INSTALLCFG=%~dp0\jresilent.properties
```

in my batch file, where `%~dp0` finds the directory of the batch file.

Comment: That's it. The docs say path to cfg file, not just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use msi for silent installation.

The command :

```
start /wait msiexec /i "%~ java8.40x64.msi " JU=0 JAVAUPDATE=0 AUTOUPDATECHECK=0 RebootYesNo=No WEB_JAVA=1 /q
```

For more information see full post [here](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/java-silent-install-version-8-and-uninstall-older-version/).